# Update ViewPager views on page scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

My ViewPager has 5 pages (which I try to make reusable), its custom PagerAdapter has a backing array with views, I initially add (inflate) them on startup, setting current page to middle page:

```
0 1 |2| 3 4
```

Now, on page scrolling I reuse one view from opposite end of the array populating it with new data (based on calendar dates) - I take the last view in array and move it to the beginning and vice versa depending on scroll direction. Then I populate it with new data.

```
Reusing views:
4 0 |1| 2 3 or 
1 2 |3| 4 0 and so on ...
```

I move and update reusable page (here 4 or 0) in `onPageSelected` of `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`, which causes a short scroll animation freezing because of time-consuming routines.

That's why I decided to execute all the slow code in a separate thread and then populate subviews in the page calling View's `post` method. Ok, it works faster now, but a little freezing is present anyway.

The question is, how can I optimize/implement such scenario properly to achieve smooth dynamic paging?